# How can I reshape a list of list from wide to long

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data.table

I have a list of list with common structure

```
require(data.table)
l <- list(a1 = list(b=data.table(rnorm(3)), c=data.table(rnorm(3)), d=data.table(rnorm(3))),
          a2 = list(b=data.table(rnorm(3)), c=data.table(rnorm(3)), d=data.table(rnorm(3))))
```

Sometimes it is easier for `lapply` to change the structure to go from a 2x3 list to a 3x2 list like:

```
+a1---b         +b---a1
   ---c           ---a2
   ---d         +c---a1
+a2---b    to     ---a2
   ---c         +d---a1
   ---d           ---a2
```

Is there an idiomatic way to do this ?

Can it be done without copying over all the tables (that may be very big) ?

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653867/best-way-to-transpose-data-table)

Comment: I do not think so, this is for data.tables not list of list (of data.tables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `purrr::transpose()` is what you are looking for.

```
(ll = purrr::transpose(l))
# $b
# $b$a1
#            V1
# 1: -0.9615584
# 2: -0.8849469
# 3:  0.4831375
# 
# $b$a2
#            V1
# 1:  0.4634884
# 2: -0.7079083
# 3: -0.4366986
# 
# 
# $c
# $c$a1
#            V1
# 1:  0.4710617
# 2: -0.4927592
# 3: -1.3484420
# 
# $c$a2
#            V1
# 1: -0.4547821
# 2:  0.5752723
# 3:  0.6272826
# 
# 
# $d
# $d$a1
#             V1
# 1:  0.80827129
# 2: -0.03640465
# 3: -1.89417912
# 
# $d$a2
#            V1
# 1:  0.1844341
# 2:  0.4557670
# 3: -0.5714462
```

Checking the dimensions:

```
length(ll)
# [1] 3
sapply(ll, length)
# b c d 
# 2 2 2
```

It [looks like its implemented in C](https://github.com/hadley/purrr/blob/master/src/transpose.c) so my guess is efficiency is fairly well-optimized and unnecessary copying is minimized.

Comment: I would think so. I think I've answered your first question (*Is there an idiomatic way to do this ?*). For your second question (*Can it be done without copying over all the tables (that may be very big) ?*), I'm not sure.