# change the hierarchy of a list in R

Tags: r, list, hierarchy, data-manipulation, reorderlist

I have list like this,

```
myList <- lapply(unique(diamonds$cut), function(x){
    lst <- lapply(unique(diamonds$color), function(y){
        dta <- diamonds[diamonds$cut == x & diamonds$color == y, ]
        lm(price ~ carat, data = dta)
    })
    names(lst) <- unique(diamonds$color)
    return(lst)
})
names(myList) <- unique(diamonds$cut)
```

The structure is,

```
> str(myList, max.level=2)
List of 5
 $ Ideal    :List of 7
  ..$ E:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ I:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ J:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ H:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ F:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ G:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ D:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
 $ Premium  :List of 7
  ..$ E:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ I:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ J:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ H:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ F:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ G:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ D:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
 $ Good     :List of 7
  ..$ E:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ I:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ J:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ H:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ F:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ G:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ D:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
 $ Very Good:List of 7
  ..$ E:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ I:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ J:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ H:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ F:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ G:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ D:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
 $ Fair     :List of 7
  ..$ E:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ I:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ J:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ H:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ F:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ G:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
  ..$ D:List of 12
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
```

I want to restructure this after having `myList` so that Each `color` will comes before `cut`. I can not change the code that creates `myList`. I have to do it after `myList` is generated. Some Help plz.

Comment: I found the solution from a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643746/how-can-i-reshape-a-list-of-list-from-wide-to-long, thanks any way, that will help me for now

Answer (score 0):

It might not be ideal, but as long as the list structure is regular, you could use a nested for loop:

```
# get names of inner and outer lists
innerNames <- names(myList[[1]])
outerNames <- names(myList)

# creat new blank list
myList2 <- list()

# restructure
for(i in innerNames) {
  for(j in outerNames)
    if(j == outerNames[1]) myList2[[i]] <- myList[[j]][i]
    else myList2[[i]] <- c(myList2[[i]], myList[[j]][i])
  }
}
```