# R - Refactor list of lists

Tags: r

Suppose I have a length M list of lists, each sub-list is of the same length (N).
How could I efficiently refactor these lists so that I now have N lists of length M?

It would be similar to if you made a matrix of the lists and sliced by a different dimension.

I.E.

```
original <- list(list(1:3, 4:6), list(2:4, 5:7))
> final
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
1, 2, 3
[[1]][[2]]
2, 3, 4

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
4, 5, 6
[[2]]
[[2]][[2]]
5, 6, 7
```

Comment: Your expected output is not clear.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, I'll happily delete if it is. I searched around a bit without success on finding the original post. Please point me in the right direction

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179197/transpose-a-list-of-lists - Let us know if this is what you want.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg  I think you are right.  Dupe tagged it.

Comment: Here is a [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646594/change-the-hierarchy-of-a-list-in-r/36647230) that might be a dupe of the above question proposed dupe.

Comment: @lmo That one is even less clear as to the desired behavior, but I think you're right.