# Importing excel files with time cells format

Tags: r, excel, time, type-conversion

I have a problem when I import my excel file in R. It convert the time cells in another format and I don't know what to do to change that.
Here is my excel file:
[image]

And here is what I obtain in R:
[image]

This is the code I used to import my files:

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx',recursive = TRUE)
file.list <- setNames(file.list, file.list)
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_xlsx, skip=20)
Actibrut <- bind_rows(df.list, .id = "id")
```

Do you know what is wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is transposed in excel. This is a problem as data.frames are column-major. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35235248/10782538) we can fix this

```
read.transposed.xlsx <- function(file, sheetIndex, as.is = TRUE) {
  df <- read_xlsx(file, sheet = sheetIndex, col_names = FALSE)
  dft <- as.data.frame(t(df[-1]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
  names(dft) <- df[[1]] 
  rownames(dft) <- NULL
  dft <- as.data.frame(lapply(dft, type.convert, as.is = as.is))
  return(dft)            
}
df <- bind_rows(lapply(file.list, \(file){
  df <- read.transposed.xlsx(df)
  df[['id']] <- file
}))
```

Afterwards you'll have to convert the columns appropriately, for example (note origin may depend on your machine):

```
df$"Woke up" <- as.POSIXct(df$"Woke up", origin = '1899-12-31')
# If it comes in as "hh:mm:ss" use
library(lubridate)
df$"Woke up" <- hms(df$"Woke up")
```

Comment: I have an error with the " \ " in  "df <- bind_rows(lapply(file.list, \(file){
  df <- read.transposed.xlsx(df)
  df[['id']] <- file
}))"

Comment: If your R version is prior to 4.1.0 you will need to replace `\(...)` with `function(...)` (arguments = `...`). Eg. `\(file)` changes to `function(file)`.

Comment: It may be beneficial to add `col_types = "text"` to `read_xlsx` (untested).

Comment: Sorry, what should "file.list" represent, I have an error message : Error in lapply(file.list, function(file) { : 
  objet 'file.list' introuvable

Comment: `file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx',recursive = TRUE)`.

Comment: oh ok, sorry I'm not a big expert in R.... I still have an error message:  Erreur : `path` must be a string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240499/discussion-between-virginie-and-oliver).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to do.
First, it appears that your data is transposed. Meaning, that your first row looks like variable names and columns contain data. You can easily transpose your data before you import into Rstudio. This will address the (..1, ..2) variable names you see when you import the data.

Secondly, import the date columns as `strings`.

The command: `df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_xlsx, skip=20)`  uses `read_xlsx` function. I think you need to explicitly specify the column variable type or import them as string.

Then you can use stringr package (or any other package) to convert strings to date variables. Also consider providing code that you have used.