# Transpose dataframe without t(), and using spread(), cast(), or melt()

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I need to transpose a dataframe without using `t()` as I want to avoid transforming it into a matrix. So, I'm using the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653867/best-way-to-transpose-data-table):

```
mydata <- data.table(col0=c("row1","row2","row3"),
                     col1=c(11,21,31),
                     col2=c(12,22,32),
                     col3=c(13,23,33))

mydata
# col0 col1 col2 col3
# row1   11   12   13
# row2   21   22   23
# row3   31   32   33

dcast(melt(mydata, id.vars = "col0"), variable ~ col0)
#    variable row1 row2 row3
# 1:     col1   11   21   31
# 2:     col2   12   22   32
# 3:     col3   13   23   33
```

And I use the same logic with the data I'm using:

```
x <- merge(as.data.frame(table(mtcars$mpg)), as.data.frame(round(prop.table(table(mtcars$mpg)),2)), by="Var1", all.x=TRUE)
data.table::dcast(data.table::melt(x, id.vars = "Var1"), variable ~ Var1)
```

It works! But it gives me a warning and a "future error":

> ```
> Warning message in data.table::melt(x, id.vars = "Var1"): “The melt
> generic in data.table has been passed a data.frame and will attempt to
> redirect to the relevant reshape2 method; please note that reshape2 is
> deprecated, and this redirection is now deprecated as well. To
> continue using melt methods from reshape2 while both libraries are
> attached, e.g. melt.list, you can prepend the namespace like
> reshape2::melt(x). In the next version, this warning will become an
> error.” Warning message in data.table::dcast(data.table::melt(x,
> id.vars = "Var1"), variable ~ : “The dcast generic in data.table has
> been passed a data.frame and will attempt to redirect to the
> reshape2::dcast; please note that reshape2 is deprecated, and this
> redirection is now deprecated as well. Please do this redirection
> yourself like reshape2::dcast(data.table::melt(x, id.vars = "Var1")).
> In the next version, this warning will become an error.”
> ```

Also, I have been trying to transpose the dataframe using a solution from [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/spreading-multiple-values/) using `dplyr::spread()` but it seems to be far more complicated than the solution from `data.table` package (when the value columns are more than 1, as in this case). I'm more used to `dplyr()` and `tidyverse()` but `data.table` solution is far simpler to just ignore it.

**Additional Information.**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.19.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C             
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] GGally_1.4.0       forcats_0.4.0      stringr_1.4.0      dplyr_0.8.3       
 [5] purrr_0.3.2        readr_1.3.1        tidyr_1.0.0        tibble_2.1.3      
 [9] ggplot2_3.2.1.9000 tidyverse_1.2.1    bigrquery_1.2.0    httr_1.4.1        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bit64_0.9-7          jsonlite_1.6         splines_3.6.0       
 [4] modelr_0.1.4         Formula_1.2-3        assertthat_0.2.1    
 [7] getPass_0.2-2        latticeExtra_0.6-28  cellranger_1.1.0    
[10] pillar_1.4.2         backports_1.1.5      lattice_0.20-38     
[13] glue_1.3.1           uuid_0.1-2           digest_0.6.21       
[16] checkmate_1.9.4      RColorBrewer_1.1-2   rvest_0.3.4         
[19] colorspace_1.4-1     htmltools_0.4.0      Matrix_1.2-17       
[22] plyr_1.8.4           psych_1.8.12         pkgconfig_2.0.3     
[25] broom_0.5.2          haven_2.1.1          scales_1.0.0        
[28] htmlTable_1.13.2     generics_0.0.2       withr_2.1.2         
[31] repr_1.0.1.9000      skimr_1.0.7          nnet_7.3-12         
[34] cli_1.1.0            mnormt_1.5-5         survival_2.44-1.1   
[37] magrittr_1.5         crayon_1.3.4         readxl_1.3.1        
[40] evaluate_0.14        fs_1.3.1             nlme_3.1-141        
[43] xml2_1.2.2           foreign_0.8-72       data.table_1.12.4   
[46] tools_3.6.0          hms_0.5.1            gargle_0.4.0        
[49] lifecycle_0.1.0      munsell_0.5.0        cluster_2.1.0       
[52] compiler_3.6.0       rlang_0.4.0          grid_3.6.0          
[55] pbdZMQ_0.3-3         IRkernel_1.0.2.9000  rstudioapi_0.10     
[58] htmlwidgets_1.5.1    base64enc_0.1-3      gtable_0.3.0        
[61] DBI_1.0.0            reshape_0.8.8        reshape2_1.4.3      
[64] R6_2.4.0             gridExtra_2.3        lubridate_1.7.4     
[67] knitr_1.25           bit_1.1-14           zeallot_0.1.0       
[70] Hmisc_4.2-0          stringi_1.4.3        parallel_3.6.0      
[73] IRdisplay_0.7.0.9000 Rcpp_1.0.2           vctrs_0.2.0         
[76] rpart_4.1-15         acepack_1.4.1        xfun_0.10           
[79] tidyselect_0.2.5
```

Comment: both `reshape2` and `data.table` are loaded? I cannot reproduce the warning/error. Please share your `sessionInfo()` as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: none of them are loaded, but both are installed (that's why I call them specifically as data.table::cast())

Comment: So I cannot get the error reproduced. package versions?

Comment: Done! Now you can see the packages information (just in case, I'm using kaggle environment)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. As mentioned in my answer, I could not reproduce the error in previous versions of `data.table` (not the very old ones) and had to update to the latest (means that this deprecation is very recent).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to transpose a dataframe without using t() as I want to avoid transforming it into a matrix.

If your only requirement is to avoid coercing your data frame into a matrix, you can use `data.table::transpose` which requires version >= 1.12.4

```
data.table::transpose(
  mydata, 
  keep.names = 'variable', 
  make.names = names(mydata)[1])

#    variable row1 row2 row3
# 1:     col1   11   21   31
# 2:     col2   12   22   32
# 3:     col3   13   23   33
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that you are passing a `data.table` object to `data.table::melt` and `data.table::dcast`.

```r
x<-merge(as.data.frame(table(mtcars$mpg)),
        as.data.frame(round(prop.table(table(mtcars$mpg)),2)), 
        by="Var1", all.x=TRUE)

data.table::dcast(data.table::melt(data.table::setDT(x), id.vars = "Var1"), 
                  variable ~ Var1)
```

***Warning(s):***

You see that by using `data.table::setDT`, that *"future error"* is resolved.

```
#> Warning in melt.data.table(data.table::setDT(x), id.vars = "Var1"):
#> 'measure.vars' [Freq.x, Freq.y] are not all of the same type. By order
#> of hierarchy, the molten data value column will be of type 'double'. All
#> measure variables not of type 'double' will be coerced too. Check DETAILS
#> in ?melt.data.table for more on coercion.
```

***Output:***

```
#>    variable 10.4 13.3 14.3 14.7   15 15.2 15.5 15.8 16.4 17.3 17.8 18.1
#> 1:   Freq.x 2.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 2.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00
#> 2:   Freq.y 0.06 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.06 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03
#>    18.7 19.2 19.7   21 21.4 21.5 22.8 24.4   26 27.3 30.4 32.4 33.9
#> 1: 1.00 2.00 1.00 2.00 2.00 1.00 2.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 2.00 1.00 1.00
#> 2: 0.03 0.06 0.03 0.06 0.06 0.03 0.06 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.06 0.03 0.03
```

***P.S.*** I could not get the error reproduced in `data.table_1.12.2` and had to update to `data.table_1.12.6`.

Answer (score 2):

The new tidyr 1.0 functions make this a lot easier:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'magrittr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     set_names
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     extract

mydata <- tibble(col0=c("row1","row2","row3"),
                 col1=c(11,21,31),
                 col2=c(12,22,32),
                 col3=c(13,23,33))

# First collect all the values in the one column
(new_data <- mydata %>% pivot_longer(col1:col3))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   col0  name  value
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 row1  col1     11
#> 2 row1  col2     12
#> 3 row1  col3     13
#> 4 row2  col1     21
#> 5 row2  col2     22
#> 6 row2  col3     23
#> 7 row3  col1     31
#> 8 row3  col2     32
#> 9 row3  col3     33

# Col0 is what we want the new column names to come from, so:
(new_data %<>% pivot_wider(names_from = col0))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   name   row1  row2  row3
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 col1     11    21    31
#> 2 col2     12    22    32
#> 3 col3     13    23    33
```

So with your `mtcars` use case:

```r
library(tidyverse)

(x <- 
    mtcars %>% 
    group_by(mpg) %>% 
    summarize(Freq.x = n(), 
              Freq.y = Freq.x/nrow(.)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-mpg) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = mpg))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 26
#>   name  `10.4` `13.3` `14.3` `14.7`   `15` `15.2` `15.5` `15.8` `16.4`
#>   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Freq~ 2      1      1      1      1      2      1      1      1     
#> 2 Freq~ 0.0625 0.0312 0.0312 0.0312 0.0312 0.0625 0.0312 0.0312 0.0312
#> # ... with 16 more variables: `17.3` <dbl>, `17.8` <dbl>, `18.1` <dbl>,
#> #   `18.7` <dbl>, `19.2` <dbl>, `19.7` <dbl>, `21` <dbl>, `21.4` <dbl>,
#> #   `21.5` <dbl>, `22.8` <dbl>, `24.4` <dbl>, `26` <dbl>, `27.3` <dbl>,
#> #   `30.4` <dbl>, `32.4` <dbl>, `33.9` <dbl>
```

I know basically nothing about `data.table`, but this gives me no red.

Now, if your values aren't all the same type, this will still give you issues - because it's still at some point stacking all the values into one column - so I was going to suggest a `nest()` approach. But then I realized... if you want to transpose the thing, and the rows aren't all the same value types, then you're ultimately trying to get values of different types into one column, aren't you? So some homogenizing conversion will be unavoidable.

<sup>Created on 2019-10-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>